# How to sum an array of values within a single key of a hash?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Should be quick one! Couldn't quite find the exact query elsewhere:

I have a hash in the form:

```
{"Chicago"=>[35.0, 5.0, 7.0], "Austin"=>[12.0, 42.0, 15.0, 8.0], ... }
```

I simply want to sum the numbers within the hash's value (array) to become:

```
{"Chicago"=> 47.0, "Austin"=> 77.0, ... }
```

I have tried `sum` and `inject` (`hash.values.each.inject(0) { |sum, x| sum + x}` etc.) and am met with "Array cannot be coerced into Integer" exceptions, and I'm not sure the correct way to go about this, though it seems a relatively simple ask!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values). Also you can replace `inject` with [Array#sum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-sum).

`hash.transform_values(&:sum)`

Comment: That's the ticket. I haven't used `transform_values` before and didn't catch it when skimming through the doc - thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Following your original approach, here is a full working solution -- it looks like you were on the right lines!

```
hash = {"Chicago"=>[35.0, 5.0, 7.0], "Austin"=>[12.0, 42.0, 15.0, 8.0]

hash.map { |city, values| [city, values.inject(0){ |sum, value| sum + value}] }.to_h
```

Phew! But that looks a bit complicated! Luckily for starters, you can call [`inject` with a symbol that names an operator](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject) to shorten it a little:

```
hash.map { |city, values| [city, values.inject(:+)] }.to_h
```

Or even better, you can call [`Array#sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-sum) to achieve the same thing in this case:

```
hash.map { |city, values| [city, values.sum] }.to_h
```

We can still do better, though. For this very common use-case of only needing to transform hash values, whilst preserving the overall hash structure, modern ruby has a builtin method for this called ... you guessed it, `transform_values`:

```
hash.transform_values { |values| values.sum }
```

And finally, simplifying this one last time:

```
hash.transform_values(&:sum)
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks for taking the time to go through it!